# How does the ping "-n" flag work? AND does it affect response time? (Linux)

Tags: linux, ping, hostname

My question has 2 sides to it, first I want to know **how does the "-n" flag work for the ping command in Linux, in particular what step does the ping program  avoid doing when I place a "-n" flag and how does this optimize the query(or speeds up the response, if so)?** and I also want to know **what is a symbolic name for a host?** which i need to know to understand the -n flag.

## My research:

The ping manual from the Linux terminal(man ping) says: "-n: Numeric output only. No attempt will be made to lookup symbolic names for host addresses". 
From that quote I already have a doubt: **I don't know what a symbolic name for a host is**, and googling didn't help...

Then I tested the ping command with the flag -n and without it, the hostname used was www.gmail.com, and the results only differ in the "FROM" section of the output: 
**Without -n I got:** 64 bytes from mia07s27-in-f165.1e100.net (216.58.219.165) 
**Using -n i got:** 64 bytes from 216.58.219.165 
So I am guessing that the symbolic name of this particular host is: "mia07s27-in-f165.1e100.net", but **what does it mean?** and **how is the process of getting this symbolic name done?**

## My thoughts:

I have a theory about how this might work:
By default, when i don't include the "-n" flag, the ping program sends the host Echo Request packets which will have a bit indicating that i didn't use the "-n" flag, so the host responds with Echo Response packets that include information about his symbolic name. When I do use the "-n" flag the bit will turn to 1(or 0, who knows..) and this will indicate the host that he doesn't have to include the extra information about his symbolic name, which in turn will make the ping response time lower, but this time is insignificant and won't be noticeable.

**Can you guys validate this theory I made up? is it correct?**

Answer (score 4):

I've never used the -n flag before, but it's rather trivial. A symbolic name is the normal name of website you would use, so lets say "google.com". However, as we know, theres no such thing as "google.com", but rather an address that corresponds to this (like 192.168.10.1, for instance). Although you might know this already, the service that does this uses DNS, Domain Name Servers. DNS maps these *symbolic names* to *numeric addresses*.

Thus according to the man page, the -n flag will save you a DNS query.

Just now on my Linux distro I ping'd google with `ping google.com`. This was the result:

```
PING google.com (173.194.123.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga15s46-in-f6.1e100.net (173.194.123.6): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=13.4 ms
64 bytes from lga15s46-in-f6.1e100.net (173.194.123.6): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from lga15s46-in-f6.1e100.net (173.194.123.6): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=13.5 ms
```

As you can see when you ping without the -n option you will do a dns query to identify the IP address of the incoming Echo Request Packets.

Then, if you ping google.com with `ping -n google.com` you will see something like this:

```
PING google.com (173.194.123.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.194.123.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=4.02 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.123.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=4.07 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.123.101: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=4.01 ms
```

Here you can see that with -n, we didnt query dns to search for what symbolic name the IP address `173.194.123.101` stood for. Also, you can see by the timing that without this query the ping time was actually shortened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So you say: "A symbolic name is the normal name of website you would use, so lets say 'google.com'", but checking what I posted above, when I pinged to "www.gmail.com" the symbolic name in the output was: "mia07s27-in-f165.1e100.net", so it's not quite clear yet since I would never use that name to search for gmail.
On the other hand, I thought that the DNS service only retrieved the IP of the host by default, but you are suggesting that it also retireves the symbolic name of the host by default, is that correct?

Comment: @SantiagoHitta I edited my answer to show the process in more detail. Keep in mind that there are several dns queries going on here. DNS just contains information on what symbolic names correspond to which addresses, so if you have information about the address or the name, you can find information about the other. When you ping google, you are looking through dns to get the address, and then when google sends you back packets, you look up google's address through dns once again. However, this last query is optional if you use the -n flag. Let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: I'm getting more confused, I have tried ping(with and without -n) with many hosts now, and i couldn't observe a difference in response time before, now you show a case where the response time is 3 times shorter... On the other hand I don't understand how can the ping response time be shorter if the DNS avoids doing a lookup, shouldn't it be only the first ping that takes longer(the dns lookup is done only once and then stored in your cache)?

Comment: And regarding the symbolic name of the host, as you could see in your example the symbolic name for google.com is "lga15s46-in-f6.1e100.net". So I imagine DNS can map google.com-->173.194.123.101 but how does DNS get this weird symbolic name? is it also stored in the DNS databases?

Comment: so "lga15s46-in-f6.1e100.net" is the reverse DNS record. So really it IS a symbolic name for the IP address, but its the symbolic name that comes up if you try to reverse the DNS process. Look into "PTR records" a little more if you find this interesting.  And with the ping times, they really do fluctuate (especially with my network haha). but I'd be cautious about trying to take internet principles and assume that ping would do the same thing. It might try to query each packet...

Comment: @SantiagoHitta You are treating Google as a monolithic entity as if it could all exist on one IP. Google has hundreds or thousands of computers and IP addresses that perform various functions, and DNS queries are multiple even in simple web requests. Typically you ask a reference computer for the domain and then drill down until you have the host, as you might parse an address by first figuring out where a state or province is, then a postal code, then finally a street and a house.

Comment: @MaxKargin
Thank you very much. So i was asking this questions to answer a work from faculty where they asked me if the "-n" flag could optimize the ping response time, I knew that the answer was NO(after trying experimentally many times, and also the professor confirmed it), but I needed to justify it. Now I know that the -n flag avoids doing a reverse DNS lookup, which I suppose shouldn't affect ping response time, because when the packet comes you already know the time it took for the packet to come, and then if you do a reverse DNS to track the source that time will remain unchanged.

Comment: @MaxKargin But then again I am just guessing, because maybe the reverse DNS is done before the packet comes to my computer and so it adds time to the Echo-Response. I'll have to keep googling.

Comment: Yes you have the right idea but I think you probably won't find that information unless you look yourself at what ping does there. It doesn't affect the ping time itself, since the ping and DNS are seperate things and the processes that handle them are seperate. Unless of course there's some sort of mutex implementation that will hold back ping (which I doubt)